# Outputting terminal to multiple columns.

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

(note: I don't mean column in the sense of a single character column).

So I'm currently debugging a program - and prints out a big long list of stuff.

What would be nice is if once it reaches the bottom of one column, it wraps around to the next column - Imagine if you had a dual screen or more setup - you could have 4-8 or so columns - and save having to scroll up.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You might get lucky by using the [`column`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) utility:

```
your_process | column
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your description it seems that the [two column virtual terminal](http://subdivi.de/~helmut/tcvt/) might solve your problem.

Disclaimer: I am the author of that software.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77690458/2063744) is my answer to the similar question.

In my case I wanted to read long texts in 2 columns and with pager, so just piping to `column` didn't work for me.

For text files I can use either `vim` or `tmux`, but for output of arbitrary command, `tmux` version maybe more useful.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
function split-tmux { tmux new-session "$*" \; split-window -h "$*" \; send-keys -t 1 PageDown \; set-window-option synchronize-panes \; attach }

split-tmux less _books/fiction/dune.md
split-tmux mcview _books/fiction/dune.md
split-tmux vim -u NONE -R _books/fiction/dune.md
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply asking how to shorten output by making it wider across multiple columns, the standard [`pr`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pr.1.html) utility allows you to do this, albeit somewhat awkwardly.

For example, try

```
command | pr -t8
```

to get the output from `command` formatted into eight columns.

The `-t` option says to remove the standard headers and footers which once upon a time were useful when generating output for a line printer, and the `8` specifies how many columns you want.

The nonstandard `-b` option (which is apparently nowadays undocumented even on Linux) says to balance the columns, i.e. prefer shorter columns as far as the specified width can accommodate them (rather than, say, produce an empty or almost empty column at the end if the parameters otherwise permit this).

Here is a simple comparison of `ls` vs `ls | pr -bt8` on a fresh Ubuntu instance (executed by way of `docker run`):

```
root@7b372041216f:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lib32  libx32  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   lib64  media   opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@7b372041216f:/# ls | pr -bt8
bin      etc      lib32    media    proc     sbin     sys      usr
boot     home     lib64    mnt      root     srv      tmp      var
dev      lib      libx32   opt      run
```

(Though perhaps notice that Ubuntu's `ls` by default colorizes its output when not connected to a pipe, which you lose by piping to `pr`.)

[POSIX `pr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html) has a fairly rich set of options, including the ones from above, so any conforming platform should support this.