# multi-column terminal multiplexer?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, gnu-screen

Let me explain what I'm looking for, hopefully for the terminal, but if it exists in an IDE, i'll take that too.

I have a laptop with a 1366x768 resolution screen; I use vim for code-writing, and I use a fairly small font in my terminal (~7pt). So, as you might imagine, there's a lot of "wasted" horizontal space, especially when coding in a compact language like python.

I just checked and found that with a 6pt. font, the maxyx of my terminal is 82 rows x 271 columns. What I'd like to have, essentially, is a single terminal with the dimensions of 246 rows x 90(89?) cols, split into 3 panes and displayed side by side. But, they would need to behave as one contiguous vertical pane, i.e., when i scroll in my editor, all three of them scroll synchronously.

Does anyone know of a hack or anything to accomplish this? Maybe for vim/screen/similar?

Patching screen might be a fun project, but I don't have time to chase that rabbit. If someone out there does, though, I'll order them a pizza or something ;)

(although if i get around to it first, i'll have to order myself a pizza)

Comment: vim and [recently] screen both offer vertical-split, as does tmux. I don't know about any way to scroll simultaneously, but tmux's 'synchronize-panes' does offer simultaneous input. Can be useful!

Comment: @amir75: your comment is more an answer than a comment. You may find this article interesting: [tmux & vim integration](https://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/vimux-simple-vim-and-tmux-integration)

Comment: @Paulo: You're right that it reads like an answer, except it doesn't satisfy the 'scroll synchronously' requirement, so I figured it was more like supplementary information. la11111: did you know about these features? If not I can describe them in an answer. p.s. Paulo: vimux looks very handy. i'll give it a go, ta

Comment: also, I think this question would be better served on superuser.com

Comment: @amir75: make it an answer, you sure deserve some reputation points for the courtesy alone. :-)

Answer (score 10):

I had the very same desire and [others want this as well](http://www.mail-archive.com/plug@lists.pdxlinux.org/msg06364.html). Lacking any options I implemented my own [two column virtual terminal](http://subdivi.de/~helmut/tcvt/). See the `--columns` option for selecting a different number of columns than two.

Comment: It does the job but has some problems, e.g. it seems to put bold/normal font markers randomly. It is also a little too heavy for low-end devices like my router but that was expected from a script.

Comment: Please use mail to report problems. Preferably including steps to reproduce. For low-end device, one likely needs to re-implement it using https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/VTE.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** based on comments, I now understand the requirement better. i.e. viewing one text file in a newspaper-like multi-column format.

It seems more like an editor feature rather than a multiplexer feature (because the 2 editors should be linked). Thanks to @romainl for mentioning `:set scrollbind`. This seems capable of doing the job in combination with some additional vim magic.

Here's an superuser q&a showing how to use `scrollbind` for your purposes: https://superuser.com/questions/243931/how-do-i-maintain-vertical-splits-with-scrollbind-in-vim .

**Original answer:**
vim and [recently] screen both offer vertical-split, as does tmux.

I don't know about any way to scroll simultaneously, but tmux's 'synchronize-panes' does offer simultaneous input. Can be useful!

- For vim, use [:vsplit](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html)
- For screen (recent versions), use [C-a |](http://aperiodic.net/screen/commands:split)
- Alternative to screen, I use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). It offers (default keys)
  `C-b %`, then you can use `C-b :setw synchronize-panes` for
  simultaneous input across panes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use `:set scrollbind` to scroll two vertical splits simultaneously in Vim.

Comment: Wow, what a plethora of responses. Yes, I am aware of windows in vim, and although I've not experimented with tmux, I'm definitely aware of v-split in screen (not too long ago, enabling this feature was a matter of patching/recompiling for most every distro I tried ;P) That's not what i'm getting at. I want one virtual terminal split into a multi-column display. In other words, say I have two panes, each 80x25; i want the leftmost pane to behave as rows 1-25, and the rightmost to behave as row 26-50 -- of the same virtual terminal... Looks like it might be time that I brushed up on my C!

Comment: You'll need a little more than brushing up your C, I think.

Comment: @la11111 ah, I see what you want now. I think it seems more like an editor feature rather than a multiplexer feature. Here's an superuser q&a showing how to use vim's `scrollbind` for your purposes: http://superuser.com/questions/243931/how-do-i-maintain-vertical-splits-with-scrollbind-in-vim

Comment: I recall another SO question that suggested `:set scrollbind`, but I can't find it now to link to it. Anyway, it seems to work well, as long as you don't mind the cursor staying in the one pane AND you don't have any wrapped lines. If you have `:set wrap` and there are too-long lines in any pane, the scrolling gets out of sync.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about an editor feature. He wants (as do I!) a feature for a terminal emulator like `screen` or `tmux` that shows the last 2*N lines of scrolling output side by side in within an N-line double-width window. An editor feature would be a *partial* solution, but I want this for everything that's displayed. I want to run `less long-file.txt` and see 2*N lines of the file, with no modifications to `less`.

Comment: interesting. The reason I thought an editor feature was because vim is read/write, so I figured it would be important to have only one vim open. For a read-only thing like 'less', then I wonder if you could script it in a terminal emulator.

Comment: i.e. run less once for each pane, on the second one scroll down one page (tmux send-keys " "), then synchronize keyboard input (in tmux it's called synchronize-panes). This would kindof work, I'd be interested to try it out. Maybe I'll have time tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I came here in search for a way to read long texts in 2 columns (newspaper-like).

`column file.txt` was not sufficient for my needs, because it rendered whole text at once and I was not able to use pager (like `less`) with it.

As suggested by other comment, I was able to use `vim` or `tmux` for this.

Here my snippets of code:

```
# vim (^F below is typed with `Ctrl+v Ctrl+f` in the terminal)

alias split-vim='vim -u NONE -R +vs "+normal ^F" "+wincmd x" "+windo set scb"'

split-vim _books/fiction/dune.md

# tmux

function split-tmux { tmux new-session "$*" \; split-window -h "$*" \; send-keys -t 1 PageDown \; set-window-option synchronize-panes \; attach }

split-tmux less _books/fiction/dune.md
split-tmux mcview _books/fiction/dune.md
split-tmux vim -u NONE -R _books/fiction/dune.md
```

`vim` variant:

- `-u NOME` option allows to skip heavy initialization to make it start faster;
- `-R` opens it read-only and without swap file;
- `+vs` splits the view;
- `+normal ^F` send keybinding to scroll one page;
- `+wincmd x` exchanges views, so that scrolled view was on the right;
- `+windo set scb` sets scrollbinding;

`tmux` variant:

- starts new session, executing rest of the args as a shell command;
- splitting window, executing same args as a shell command in it (second time);
- sends PageDown keystroke to the second pane;
- sets option to sync panes;

Actually, I like `tmux` variant more, because of it's flexibility, though, I guess, it takes a bit more resources.